# Hibernate Validator showing garbage text in i18n message

Tags: java, jsp, hibernate-validator

It is showing below message in borwser:

> àª¨àª¾àª® à«« àª¥à«€ à«§à«¨ àª…àª•à«àª·àª° àª¸à«àª§à«€ àª¹à«‹àªµà«àª‚ àªœà«‹àªˆàª.

**POJO**

```
@Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length=45)
@Size(max=12,min=5,message = "{error.name.range}")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

**PROPERTIES-**
**validation_en.properties**

> error.name.required=Please enter name.
> error.name.duplicate=Name already exits.
> error.name.range = Name should be 5-12 characters long.

**validation_gu.properties**

> error.name.required=some other language.
> error.name.duplicate=some other language.
> error.name.range = some other language.

**XML**

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator">
    
    
</mvc:annotation-driven>
 <!-- Localization of hibernate messages during validation!-->
<bean id="validationMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:validation" />
</bean>

<bean name="validator"  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="validationMessageSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**JSP:**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     <tr>
                <td width="50%" align="right" style="padding-right:25px">
                    <label for="">
                        <spring:message code="master.user.name" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td  width="50%">
                    <form:input path="name" id="name"/> 
                    <form:errors path="name"></form:errors>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

**JAR**

**hibernate-validator-5.1.1.Final.jar**

Comment: What character set and encoding does the browser think this is?

Comment: I tried UTF-8 in properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my problem... one hint is enough...
Thank you

@Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen

```
<bean id="validationMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:validation" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Having a name with a non-ascii character in it, is one of the most efficient ways to see problems like yours up early   When you have the time, you may want to look into how UTF-8 works to explain why you see what you do, and why changing it fixes it.